# Neo4j and Ruby/Rails: How to only return nodes based on user permissions

Tags: ruby, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j.rb

1. How to return an index of only Items where the User has permission?
2. How to return an index of only Items where the Group a User is in has permission?
3. How to return a single item only if a User has permission?
4. How to return a single item only if the Group a User is in has permission?

*Note: I know it's possible to query for `Item.all`, then iterate through the array and pull out only items where `.has_permissions == User`, but this completely ignores the benefits of having everything in a graph, so is not an answer.*

---

To keep this simple, let's say there are 3 objects:

- An Item
- A User
- A Group

Typical graph situations:

```
(User)<-[:HAS_PERMISSIONS]-(Item)
(Group)<-[:HAS_PERMISSIONS]-(Item)
(Group)-[:HAS_MEMBERS]->(User)
```

With the models:

```
class Item 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name, type: String
  property :description, type: String

  has_many :out, :user_permission_to, type: :PERMISSION_TO, model_class: :User
  has_many :out, :group_permission_to, type: :PERMISSION_TO, model_class: :Group
end

class Identity 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :username, type: String

  has_many :in, :permission_to, type: :PERMISSION_TO, model_class: :Item
  has_many :in, :groups, type: :GROUP_MEMBER, model_class: :Group
end

class Group 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :group_name, type: String

  has_many :in, :permission_to, type: :PERMISSION_TO, model_class: :Item
  has_many :out, :members, type: :GROUP_MEMBER, model_class: :User
end
```

And with the simple controller:

```
# GET /items
def index
  @items = Item.all
  render json: @items
end

# GET /item/1
def show
  render json: @item
end
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: Sure; added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I'd suggest checking out [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/why-you-should-use-neo4j-in-your-next-ruby-app/) (the second half covers access control which is very similar)

"How to return an index of only Items where the User has permission?"

You could do this a couple of ways.  More explicitly:

```
identity.as(:id).query.match("(id)<-[PERMISSION_TO*1..2]-(item:Item)").pluck(:item)
```

Alternatively, I think that this would work:

```
identity.permission_to(rel_length: 1..2)
```

"How to return an index of only Items where the Group a User is in has permission?"

Simple:

```
identity.groups.permission_to
```

"How to return a single item only if a User has permission?"

For the two solutions above:

```
identity.as(:id).query.match("(id)<-[PERMISSION_TO*1..2]-(item:Item)").limit(1).pluck(:item)

# or

identity.permission_to(rel_length: 1..2).first
```

"How to return a single item only if the Group a User is in has permission?"

```
identity.groups.permission_to
```

Separately, some feedback:

Using the term "index" the way you're using it is a bit confusing because Neo4j has indexes which allow for performant querying of properties on labels.

I would probably make my models like this:

```
class Item 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name, type: String
  property :description, type: String

  has_many :in, :users_with_permission, type: :CAN_ACCESS, model_class: :Identity
  has_many :in, :groups_with_permission, type: :CAN_ACCESS, model_class: :Group
end

class Identity 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :username, type: String

  has_many :out, :accessible_items, type: :CAN_ACCESS, model_class: :Item
  has_many :out, :groups, type: :IN_GROUP # Don't need `model_class: :Group` here
end

class Group 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :group_name, type: String

  has_many :out, :accessible_items, type: :CAN_ACCESS, model_class: :Item
  has_many :in, :members, type: :IN_GROUP, model_class: :Identity
  # You could also do:
  # has_many :in, :members, model_class: :Identity, origin: :groups
end
```